# Get the html element of the selected event in kendo scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I was wondering how can I get in the html element with ".k-event" class, contains selected event in function binded to edit event of the Scheduler?

```
$("#src-ap-01-scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date(),
    allDaySlot: false,
    editable: {
       template: $("#scr-ap-01-editor").html()
    },
    edit: function(e){
       // i have tried these 
       // e.currentTarget
       // e.container.closest("k-event")
    }
 })
```

I've logged the (e) on the function but I have no idea how to get the .k-event element from inside of the function. I hope you guys have some idea to get this element, any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get selected event element put this code in function triggered on edit:

```
edit: function(e){
    var uid = e.container.attr('data-uid');
    var element = e.sender.element.find('div.k-event[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: I already apply this and its' work for the event, thanks. anyway if the he click the tile that doesn't have even what should i do to get the element too

Comment: Your English is hard :) But if I understand you well you should get element when you click on empty tile as well. It's create evement under the edit window and get reference to this as well. Check this example I've made for you: http://dojo.telerik.com/OmifO . If you have any problem modify this fiddle to show it.

Comment: @JarosławKończak Is it possible to get the html of that cell on which we click ?

Comment: @I'm nidhin Do you mean td element? I can't find easy way to get it. If I must do it I think I would use offset() function on .k-event div and find td which has a similar position.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer doesn't work in Kendo UI v2015.1.318, and here's my quick solution for this issue.

```js
edit: function(e) {
    if (e.event.YOUR_EVENT_CONDITION) {
        // Allow the user to edit this event!
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = e.sender.element.find('div.k-event[data-uid="'+e.event.uid+'"]');
        if (element)
            $(element).notify("You can't modify a completed event.", {className: "error", placement: "top", autoHideDelay: 3000});
        else
            $.notify("You can't modify a completed event.", "error");
    }
}
```

I'm using notify.js to display a popup message right on the selected event UI only if it exists. Please visit the following link for notify.js.

http://notifyjs.com/